What's the name of this Animation in this android app?
I am looking for how to implement this animation, or what is the name of this animation and whether is it available normally within Android Material or it requires any customization.
Animation preview
I tried some libraries like "Animitoo" but it does not contain such a smooth animation.

Custom animation. You can try to slow down animations speed in a phone developer settings. It will make it easier to analyze the animation, step by step.

Tellonym seems to be a ReactNative Product, based on what Wappalyzer says. Based on this, it might be hard to give you the name of the animation as there's a fair amount of chance that it's completely custom.
It might be an animation available directly using the Android Kit but I'm not sure.
After some researches, I came across this https://static.tellonym.me/public/info/licenses.txt
In this file I searched for the animation libraries that might be stated and found :
https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated
https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/animating-styles-and-props
Which seem to confirm the fact that it might be fully customized.
I'm letting you dive deep in the documentation as I don't currently have the time to look it up.
I hope this will help you in any way.
tldr;
There's a high probability it's a custom animation.
